# python3 TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='~/file1' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

Tags: python-3.x

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-TNm', '--file1', type=argparse.FileType('r'), required=True)

parser.add_argument('-Css', '--file2', type=argparse.FileType('w'), required=True)

parser.add_argument('-Iacs', '--file3',type=argparse.FileType('w'), required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

def main(args):

        with open(args.file1) as TN, open(args.file2) as Cs, open(args.file3) as Ia:

            for line in enumerate(TN):
                ....................   #processing each line and its indice


if __name__ == '__main__':

       main(args)
```

I run this script by

```
python3 ~/script.py -TNm ~/file1 -Css ~/file2 -Iacs ~/file3
```

And an error was given:

```
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='~/file1' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Is there something wrong with `enumerate(TN)`?

Comment: `type=argparse.FileType('r')` opens the file for you.  `open(args.file1) as TN` is trying to open an open file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed type=argparse.FileType('r') and it works.